# File System Performance in Linux and Windows

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, ntfs, htpc

I have built a HTPC with AMD Athlon 5350, which was completely sufficient. The system was running Windows 10 running in SSD and big HDD for backups in NTFS. Somehow there is a problem with network transfer speeds between PCs - with Samba I can get speeds up to 100 MB/s in my local network and FTP transfers which I would prefer don't get more than 10 MB/s. No idea why.

Anyway, I decided to build a new PC using Dell 7010 with 3470s. I plan to transfer the backup HDD.

The question is, which setup to choose.

I would prefer to switch to Ubuntu as I was always running Virtual Linux Machines on my previous computer. The question is - how will the NTFS HDD behave if I stay with Linux? Will it limit the transfer speeds? Will it consume lots of CPU when writing/reading? Should I try to reformat the HDD to Linux native FS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

NTFS filesystem won't significantly impact transfer speeds but its not ideal as it's proprietary and Linux support, while present, is limited and not that great.  You would be better off with a Linux-Centric FS - and that will give better integrity and fewer edge cases/perms issues - so yes, reformat hdd.